# How to return just the id number from queryset for a counter?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm really just a beginner in python and django...
I'm looking for a way on how to get just the id of the last item in the queryset as a counter of posts for my project. I know about the ModelName.objects.last or .latest() however if I use last i still get the "Topic object (id)" I need just the id without the preceding text. Could anyone help me?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, try this `ModelName.objects.last().id`

Comment: OH wow, that's it! I was trying the other way ModelName.objects.id.last without any avail. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!